# Hosted Checkout Pages tab missing within Service Settings for PayFlow Pro

Tags: payflowpro

We use **PayFlow Pro** (traditional integration - HTTPS) and would like to implement it with **Hosted Pages**.  However, within PayPal Manager, under the tab for **Service Settings**, I do not see an area for **Hosted Checkout Pages**. All it shows for any of our accounts is PayFlow Pro - Allowed IP Addresses.

Is there a prerequisite setting that must be set first in order to configure **Hosted Checkout Pages**?

Thanks, Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the legacy version of Payflow Pro which Hosted Checkout Pages did not comes together in bundle. See [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#who-should-use-this-document).In case you wanted the Hosted Checkout Pages to available in your account, you need to ring the Payflow Support to add this functions to your Payflow Pro service.

Comment: Thanks- you were correct.  I had to call them and they added it, along with the Advance Fraud Protection.  Thanks, Jim